# Where can I find maps of Rifts Earth?

Tags: maps, rifts

Where can I find maps of Rifts Earth, especially political maps that show the borders of North American nations like the CS, the Manistique Imperium, the Federation of Magic, etc. around 110 P.A. (2396)?

Comment: Added in a date, since there have been several maps of (eg) the CS over the years as it's gone on various campaigns.

Answer (score 6):

Your first stop for maps of Rifts Earth is the *Rifts Game Master Guide*. Pages 332 through 352 cover the borders of most notable locations in Rifts Earth: the Coalition States, Federation of Magic, Manistique, Northern Gun, Lazlo, Tolkeen, the Canadian Hivelands, the New West Territories, the Vampire Kingdoms, the Pecos Empire, Atlantis, the British Isles, Western Europe, Russia, Japan, Australia, and the Phoenix Empire in Africa.

The borders (current and hoped-for) of the Coalition States are also shown and discussed on pages 13–14 of *Rifts Sourcebook*.

*Siege on Tolkeen: Chapter One* describes on pages 112–114 the extent of the Kingdom of Tolkeen, and features a nicely detailed map of Rifts Wisconsin. Detailed information on European, Japanese, and Australian territories also appear in the last installment of this series, *Siege on Tolkeen: Aftermath* (pages 183, 188, and 196 for maps and surrounding descriptions).

Answer (score 1):

[My Rifts collection](http://3rdageofdragonwright.blogspot.com/2011/02/rifts-east.html) includes a few fan and official maps of North America, Atlantis, and South America.

Comment: Can you expand on its contents and provenance so that people don't just think this is a spam link and (correctly) avoid clicking on it?